# Explanation of output of C code

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

I came across this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int x;
    float t;
    scanf("%f",&t);
    printf("%d\n",t);
    x=90;
    printf("%f\n",x);
    {
        x=1;
        printf("%f\n",x);
        {
            x=30;
            printf("%f\n",x);
        }
        printf("%f\n",x);
    }
    printf("%f\n",x);
}
```

Glancing at it I thought of it as some undefined output as quoted in standards:

> A warning: printf uses its first argument to decide how many arguments
>   follow and what their type is. It will get confused, and you will get
>   wrong answers, if there are not enough arguments of if they are the
>   wrong type.

But the output didn't let me leave this question without giving it second thought.
(input given is 23).

```
23 
0
23.000000
23.000000
23.000000
23.000000
23.000000
```

Why always 23.00000? What is the compiler actually trying to do here? Instead of messing around with the value stored at `x`, why does it print the value of `t`? Does it have any explanation, because there seems something defined about this undefined output (pun intended).

### Edit:

I am using gcc compiler on 32 bit machine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The program behavior is undefined, the compiler is permitted to do anything at all.

That said, I am able to reproduce this behavior on my system and a glance at the assembly output shows what happens:

`printf("%d\n",t);` begins by loading the floating point value from `t` into the CPU register `%xmm0` which is used on my platform to pass floating-point arguments to functions. That register is not accessed by this call to `printf()`, since it is looking for an integer input instead.

None of the subsequent calls to `printf()` load any values into `%xmm0`, since you're not passing any floating-point values into printf or into any other function. But when each `printf` encounters `%f` in its format string, it reads from `%xmm0`, which still contains `23.0`

Assembly output, from CLang, using a simpler program with `float t = 23.0;`

```
.LCPI0_0:
    .quad   4627167142146473984     # double 2.300000e+01
...
    movl    $.L.str, %edi          # .L.str is "%d\n"
    movsd   .LCPI0_0(%rip), %xmm0  # 23.0 stored in xmm0 here
    movb    $1, %al
    callq   printf                 # this printf will print %esi

    movl    $90, %esi              # 90 stored in %esi here
    movl    $.L.str1, %edi         # .L.str1 is "%f\n"
    xorb    %al, %al
    callq   printf                 # but this printf will print %xmm0
```

Comment: Thanks..That clarifies everything. Sort of unintended hack in itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to know what is producing the behavior here, you need to look at the assembly code this (completely broken) C code is being translated to for your particular compiler and CPU.

Comment: Speculating -- for your compiler ints and floats have different sized representations.  When you look at a float as an int, it is seeing the unused bits in your float and showing 0.  When you are showing an int as a float, it is looking on the stack past the int part to find bits of a completely different value.

Comment: Both float and int are of same size 4 bytes on my machine.

Comment: Cubbi has the right answer; not position on stack but which register is used (highly compiler/processor dependent behavior, of course)